# Azure Devops pipeline failing when tests are running

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm running a web project pipeline, which is built in angular, however, every time it fails at the point of test with the error 'Your computer has run out of resources. Sign out of Windows or restart your computer and try again.

I've tried rerunning the pipeline but it's still the same result. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What agent you are using to run the tests in pipeline? Microsoft-hosted agents or self-hosted agents? If you are using Microsoft-hosted agents, try to use the self-hosted agents.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run your pipeline, you need to know that each Microsoft-hosted Windows agent has 2 core CPU, 7 GB of RAM and 14 GB of SSD disk space. However, since the series of preinstalled software on the agent, the actual available resources (such as disk space and CPU utilization) will be less than that. Users cannot control these resources on Microsoft-hosted agents.

If the build and test processes of your project need to consume more resources on the agent, I recommend you try to set up the [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops) to run the pipeline. Since the Self-hosted agents are normally installed on yourself own local machines (or VMs), you can control/expand the disk space, CPU and other resources on the machines based on your demands.

---

Comment: Is there any update from you? Have you tried to use the self-hosted agents to run the test job? Does that work for you? @AmenawonEsezobor